# PhoneGap camera getPictue - get full image quality

Tags: image, cordova, camera

I am making an app where an photo is taken and sent to the server, but the files that get sent are of low quality. It seems that when I take a photo using iOS native camera app it come out as a very sharp picture, but when using PhoneGap it reduces the quality massively.

I have set the image quality to 100 etc:

```
function capturePhoto() {
// Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onPhotoURIFail, { 
    quality: 100, 
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    //destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
    sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG
});
```

}

But still seems to give a real blurry image.

Has anyone else had this problem? I have also tried using the DATA_URL to get the base64 encoded image, but this makes the app go so slow that I couldn't get to a stage to send to the server.

Is there a way to use the original LOSSLESS file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
function capturePhoto() {

            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onPhotoURIFail, { 
                quality: 50, 
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
                correctOrientation: false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
                targetWidth: 1500,
                targetHeight: 1500

            });
}
```

Im not sure why mine wouldn't work before, but it may have been because I was trying it on my iPad? I can't quite remember if I had the same problem with my iPhone also at that time.

Also the way the imageURI is retrieved may have made a difference, not sure about that either, but here is my code to get the image URI:

```
function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI){

    $('#imagePreview img.smallImage').attr("src", imageURI); 


}
```

And then just get the URI from the image when you want to send. It prety much exactly like all the examples but for some reason didn't work before.

Make sure you have your plugins using the latest version too. That's about it!